# Globally set NoRecords setting for kendo grid

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have implemented kendo grid in my project. I want to show "No Records Available" message to grid if data is not present. I set noRecords to true for my grid and it is working as expected. Now I have so many grids in my project so I want to globally set this setting for all the grids.

Is there a way to achieve so?

Here is my sample code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>Kendo UI Snippet</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.1.117/styles/kendo.common.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.1.117/styles/kendo.rtl.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.1.117/styles/kendo.silver.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.1.117/styles/kendo.mobile.all.min.css"/>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.1.117/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  First Grid:
<div id="grid"></div>
  Second Grid:
  <div id="grid1"></div>
<script>
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
  columns: [
    { field: "name" },
    { field: "age" }
  ],
  pageable: true,
  noRecords: {
    template: "No data available"
  },
  dataSource: {
    page: 1,
    pageSize: 10
  }
});

  $("#grid1").kendoGrid({
  columns: [
    { field: "name" },
    { field: "age" }
  ],
  pageable: true,
  dataSource: {
    page: 1,
    pageSize: 10
  }
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

You can find a working dojo [here](https://dojo.telerik.com/IFePAM/3).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hi you can extend the grid like this. You can put this in a separate js file and include it before you use a grid.

```
(function ($, kendo) {

var _init = kendo.ui.Grid.fn.init;
var extendedGrid = kendo.ui.Grid.extend({

    init: function (element, options) {           
        var getTemplate = function (textP, iconP) {
            var icon = iconP || 'icon';
            var text = textP || 'No data available';
            var tpl = `<div class="no-records-table"><div class="no-records-table-cell"><div class="grid-no-records-icon ${icon}"></div><div>${text}</div></div></div>`;
            return tpl;
        }

        options = $.extend({                
            noRecords: {
                template: getTemplate(options.noRecordsText, options.noRecordsIcon)
            }
        }, options);

        //call the base constructor.
        _init.call(this, element, options);                
    }               
});
kendo.ui.plugin(extendedGrid);
}(window.kendo.jQuery, window.kendo));
```

You can check the the [dojo here](https://dojo.telerik.com/IFePAM/5)